# Efficient Robust Private Set Intersection Additive ElGamal

Tags: elgamal-encryption, private-set-intersection

I am trying to implement [Efficient Robust Private Set Intersection](http://www.ece.umd.edu/~danadach/MyPapers/set-int.pdf) using additive ElGamal.

I am trying to run the full protocol mentioned in Section 3.4 on the following inputs:

- $p = 17$ (prime)
- $g = 6$ (generator)
- $x = 5$ (private key)
- $k = g^x \pmod p = 6^5 \pmod{17} = 7$ (public key)

Suppose the clients inputs are 1, 2. Then $P(x) = (x-1)(x-2) = x^2-3x+2$, and therefore the coeffiecients to encrypt are $(1, -3, 2)$. I chose $y = 10$ and so the encrypted values are:

- $1$ becomes $(15,12)$
- $-3$ becomes $(15, 1)$
- $2$  becomes $(15, 4)$.

The Server Side Input Set $S=\{1\}$ and the random value $r0$ corresponding to $\{1\}$ is $r_0=2$.

---

With the above problem in context, I have some questions:

1. What does `P 0,j` refer to in Step 7. Can you please give an example?
2. In Step 8, suddenly variable `i` is introduced along with `j`. What does `i, j`, refer to?
3. In Step 8, `ENC()` function has a `;` in between. How do we interpret `ENC(a;b)`?

Comment: Could you please clarify where your problem exactly lies in the mentioned step (e.g., by editing your question)?

Comment: I just approved [this edit suggestion](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/5473) from an anonymous user. (It still needs someone else to approve it.) I assume that was you? You [might want](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to [register an account](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) here, so that you'll be able to edit your posts more easily.

Comment: @figlesquidge Good find btw. (First time the chat showed me it's real value.)